# Creating unique id with jquery to use in bxslider

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider, unique-id

I guess this is pretty simple but I have no experience with jquery whatsoever. I'm using bxslider in every post I post in my wordpress theme and need the jquery to point to numerous unique id's, not only to work1, but work2, work3 and so on.

```
The markup is this:
<ul id="work1">
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>

<ul id="work2">
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>

...
```

And the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#work1').after('<div class="work-pager"></div>');
    jQuery('#work1').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    infiniteLoop: false,
    speed: 500,
    pause: 8000,
    auto: false,
    pager: true,
    controls: false,
    pagerSelector: '.work-pager'
     });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findNewId() {
    var i = 0;
    while(1) {
      if($('#work'+i).size()==0) return 'work'+i;
      i++;
    }
}
$('ul').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('id',findNewId());
});
```

This should do the trick. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g5xeg/)

Comment: The unique id naming works like a glove. Thanks! Still I have this problem that only the first slider works while the rest collapses. So I guess there's another problem somewhere. Anywho thanks again.